# Speedup index build in db2 LUW

Tags: indexing, db2-luw

I want to speedup index build in db2 10.5.0.10, I have set DB2_SMP_INDEX_CREATE to increase the number of agents used to build the index, I have also increased sortheap, sheapthres_shr and bufferpools size, but although the number of agents increases the speed of index build does not change, database uses less than 20 percent of sortheap, sheapthres_shr and instance memory and server has multiple idle cpus, Is there any idea?

Comment: What are the exact current values of sortheap, shespthred_shr, num_ioservers, DB2_SMP_INDEX_CREATE? The same is for sort_[consumer_]shrheap_top of mon_get_dataase (top sort mem use). Have you tried to speed up prefetching with DB2_PARALLEL_IO & block-based bufferpool?

Comment: SORTHEAP = AUTOMATIC(50000),
SHEAPTHRES_SHR = AUTOMATIC(2000000),
NUM_IOSERVERS = AUTOMATIC(40),
DB2_SMP_INDEX_CREATE=10,
SORT_SHRHEAP_TOP=500010,
I also set DB2_PARALLEL_IO for the tablespace to 10, but elapsed time for the index build  was the same before and after these settings.

Comment: You need to restart the instance after setting DB2_PARALLEL_IO. Have you done it? Have you tried block based bufferpool (you may dedicate significant percentage like 50% or even more for this area, the database reactivation is needed)?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted the instance and I have also tried block based bufferpool.

Comment: Try to fix SORTHEAP with significantly larger value, say, 100 or 200k pages.

Comment: I have increased SORTHEAP to 200k pages, but nothing has changed.